# How do I display real names instead of usernames for referenced users?

Tags: views, 8

Here are the steps which I followed:

1. Added the user referenced field in the content type so one author can add multiple users who contributed in that content.
2. Using views i am showing the content and showing the users who contributed in this node.

My issue is that the view is showing the usernames of all the users. I want to convert those usernames to the Display name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with most problems this one too can be solved in more than one way.

Probably the easiest, common, and "most Drupal" way is through using **View modes**.

### View modes

View modes are different ways of displaying entity content, depending on the context. Don't confuse them with Views module that is used for building lists of entities, they are completely different things.

An example of a View mode: you want the user profile page to show all user user fields, but in a lot of other places on the site you need the username and their geo-location, so you keep the `Default` User View mode for profiles, and create a new View mode where you only enable the username and geofield. Then activate the new user view mode in all places where you need to show the user with their geo-info.

In your case you have a User Reference field in Content Views and you want to change how the user info from that field is presented:

1. Create a new User View mode under People `Manage display` (`/admin/config/people/accounts/display`) > `Custom display settings`
2. Enable the newly created View mode. After you enable it and `Save` the page will reaload and a new Drupal tab will appear named after your new View mode.
3. Visit the page of the newly created View mode (click on that tab) and adjust which user fields you want to show under that View. In your case that might be firstName and lastName, disable all others by dragging them down to the Disabled list (and Save).
4. Edit your Content Views (this is now the list of content you mention in your question, not the View modes), edit the User reference field and change the `View mode` option to the one you created in step 1.

[image: UserReference View mode in Views]

Now your User reference field will show only the user fields you have enabled in the View mode on People account configuration.

You can use this View mode in other places too where you want any User data to display only as the Display names.

---

### Through Views

Alternatively, you can achieve the same result with Contextual filters within a Views Block Display to show only users referenced by the article you're currently viewing, and only showing that Block on the pages of that specific Content Type.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I followed your steps but i could not understand step 4. Can you please describe more?

Comment: I added a screenshot to clarify. In step 4 you go to your views where you're building your list of content. One of the fields there is the User reference field, as you mention in your question. Edit that field settings as you see in the screenshot, change the View mode dropdown from `Default` to your new one (`RealName` in the screenshot).

Comment: Thanks for adding screenshoot. I could not understand what is formatter in your screenshoot?

Comment: Bricks is a module I use on the site where I took the screenshot, it isn't relevant to your case, you don't need Bricks. Set the `Formatter` to Default or which ever option suits you best, as long as it allows for Views mode to be chosen. I think the Formatter might depend on what you have set for that field under its settings.

Comment: When i select the " Rendered Entity" Formatter in Views field settings then "People" view mode show up in the drop down. And this only visible to the logged in users. Can we make this visible for all users?

Comment: Is "People" your new View mode from step 1? User profiles have their own Permission "View user information". That applies to profiles in general, not just the one view. If you don't want the users to see profile pages, but do want to see the Views Display name, then turn off the node access check in Views under `Query settings`: `Disable SQL rewriting` but only do that if you know that your problem is about the permissions, and not this question View modes in general.

Comment: Yes, "People: is my view mode which i created from step 1. I dont want to `Disable Sql rewriting`. I am using node access module to restrict users from editing the nodes. I am allowing the referenced user to edit that specific node.

Comment: Don't disable the node access check in Views since you need it. I guess you better submit a new question will all the permission details to get answer about why it's not visible.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you describe the second approach? The contextual filters thing?

Comment: It's very similar for the Contextual filters solution. Create your content Views, add the Fields for the Display name, you'll probably need Relationship for the reference field, then you can add the Display name field. You will see a list of all nodes. Then you add the Contextual filter for ID, and set Default value to ID from URL. Then place block on node pages, it will only show the node you're viewing currently. You can search here for Contextual filter node ID to find similar answers.